# PHP Notice: Array to string conversion on line 10

Tags: php

I am a newbie and have written some code in PHP which gives me above mentioned notice.
My program works perfectly but i want to resolve the notice.
I know i can turn off the notice, but i dont want to do that.
Please let me know how can i fix it.

My code -

```
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' =>  array(
        'host'  =>  '127.0.0.1',
        'username'  =>  'root',
        'password'  =>  '',
        'database'  =>  'app'
    )
);


            $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
            $path = explode('/', 'mysql/host');

            foreach($path as $bit){                
                if(isset($config[$bit])){
                    $config = $config[$bit];
                }
            }

            echo $config;
```

My output from

```
echo $config;
```

is 127.0.0.1 and it is as expected.

But i am getting the notice on line -

```
$config = $GLOBALS['config'];
```

Please help.

Comment: Why are you using `$GLOBALS` tho? Normally, you use that inside a function to get a variable outside the function scope. I don't see any functions in your example tho.

Comment: Which line is line 10?

Comment: Why do people _ever_ use `$GLOBALS`? If you want to access a global variable inside a function, use a `global $config;` declaration.

Comment: why are you declaring `$config` as an array, then later changing it to a string? That sort of coding is just inviting problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line right before the $config = $GLOBALS['config']

```
$config = array();
```

Comment: Glad it worked. You can choose this as the answer by clicking on the checkmark underneath the number with the arrows.

Comment: I will, once I have 15 reputation :)